# How can I connect to a database in ASP.NET Core without Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I connect to a database from ASP.NET Core and Angular without Entity Framework?

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultParkingConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-CD0M0C3\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ParkingSystem2;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd"
  },
```

How can I get connection string in Web API controller?

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultParkingConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET Core works different than ASP.NET, so you need to map the connection strings defined in `appsettings.json` to a class or variable to be accessed throughout the application. Try the following approach:

1. Create `appSettings.json`:

   ```
   {
   "ConnectionStrings": {
       "DefaultParkingConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-CD0M0C3\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ParkingSystem2;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create a new class `ConnectionStrings` to map the connection strings defined in `appSettings.json` to it:

   ```
   using System;

   namespace Test
   {
       public class ConnectionStrings 
       {
           public string DefaultParkingConnection{ get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. In `Startup.cs`, write the following code:

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           this.Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           //Map the configuration
           var connectionSection = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
           services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(connectionSection );            
       }

       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
       {
           // Configure 
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now in your controllers, you can easily use it without creating the instance of the class:

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

   namespace Test.Controllers
   {
       [ApiController]
       [Route("api/account")]
       public class AccountController : ControllerBase
       {
           private readonly ConnectionStrings connectionStrings;

           public AccountController(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
           {
               this.connectionStrings = connectionStrings.Value;
           }

           [HttpGet, Route("test")]
           public IActionResult Test()
           {
               return Ok("test");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: How do I access the route to know if there was a connection?

Comment: This answer would benefit from being updated to reflect the .NET 6+ reality of Startup.cs being merged into Program.cs (in other words, in .NET 6+ there is no Startup.cs file anymore).

Answer (score 5):

You could inject `IConfiguration` in api controller:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

    public ValuesController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;

        string constr  = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultParkingConnection");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has just release sqlclient for asp.net core for access to ado.net.

from the packagemanager

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient -Version 1.0.19269.1
```

Comment: This has the beginnings of being useful, but it doesn't explain how to connect to a database, just that there is a library that may or may not add support for it. You can improve this answer by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58945032/edit) and adding an explanation on _how_ to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to create a connection to a database.