# .NET Framework and Entity Framework Core: How can I get hold of the connection string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-4.7.2

I've installed EF Core in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 class library. This is just a project containing some specific functionality, not the `StartUp` project in the solution. The project with EF Core is then referenced by the main project, where the `web.config` and IoC setup lives. The solution is for a web site.

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/platforms/#net-framework), .NET Framework 4.7.2 is supported.

The problem is injecting or otherwise fetching the connection string, or probably any other configuration/appsettings value.

Let's say this is my `DbContext` class:

```
public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"] == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Hey!");
            }

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run commands like `Add-Migration` or `Remove-Migration`, the `AppSettings["ConnectionString"]` is null, and the exception gets thrown.

I think this is due to the application being in "design mode", and the `web.config` hasn't been read. I need to be able to specify different connection strings for different environments.

Any ideas to how I can get the connection string from either the `<appSettings>` or the `<connectionStrings>`?

Edit: I also want to add that the solution uses Structuremap for IoC, and I can't inject into the DbContext when running the migration commands in the package manager console.

Comment: Try below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940341/how-can-i-connect-to-a-database-in-asp-net-core-without-entity-framework

Comment: @JoelDharansingh I'd love to inject the connection string, but as I forgot to mention, I can't inject into the DbContext. Seems like the IoC isn't initialized yet. I edited the post to mention that now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: I wasn't clear, but I've already tried this. It didn't work either.